# How to query in linq that the field that should be in the where clause is a concatenation of fields

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Sorry for the title, I just can't figure out how to come up with a well defined title. But anyway I'll just have to explain to you my problem.

I've made a query that will look for a certain student specified by its full name.

SQL version:

```
SELECT * FROM Student as s WHERE concat(s.lastname,', ',s.firstname,' ',s.middlename) = myvalue
```

I've tried many times already converting it to linq query with string.concat and string.join but it gives me an error:

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Concat(System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

Maybe someone can help. Thanks!

Student:

```
public class Student{
public int StudentID { get; set; }
public string Firstname { get; set; }
public string Middlename { get; set; }
public string Lastname { get; set; }
public ...
}
```

And my linq query:

```
public void FindStudent(string fullname){

using(MyContext _ctx = new MyContext()){

var _query = from stud in _ctx.Student
where string.concat(stud.Lastname.Trim(),' ',stud.Firstname.Trim(),' ',stud.Middlename.Trim()) == fullname

select new{

StudentID = stud.StudentID,
Firstname = stud.Firstname,
Middlename = stud.Middlename,
Lastname = stud.Lastname

}
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could share the c# code as well as the type defintion of student and myvalue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Concat etc (and as you found they're not supported) so just add the strings

```
var q = Students.Where(
          s => s.LastName + ", " + s.FirstName + ", " + s.MiddleName == FullName);
```

In Entity Framework this will produce SQL similar to

```
SELECT ...
FROM [Students] AS [t0]
WHERE (([t0].[LastName] + @p0) + [t0].[FirstName] + ....) = @p3
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing single string for last, first and middle names, pass them separately:

```
var students = from s in db.Students
               where s.LastName == lastName &&
                     s.FirstName == firstName &&
                     s.MiddleName == middleName
               select s;
```

If you have only string in format "lastName, firstName middleName", then you can parse it this way:

```
string name = "Downey, Robert Jr";
var match = Regex.Match(name, @"(?<last>\w+),\s+(?<first>\w+)\s+(?<middle>\w+)");
string lastName = match.Groups["last"].Value;
string firstName = match.Groups["first"].Value;
string middleName = match.Groups["middle"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a VIEW in your SQL Server database. That VIEW then contains all the fields of Student and the concatenated fields as a new field, say FullName:

```
CREATE VIEW StudentQuery
AS
SELECT *, LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName AS FullName
FROM Student
```

Then in Entity Framework, you map this VIEW to an Entity, and then you query that entity.

This way, your LINQ query is more readable and more performant, because you let the database handle the concatenation work.